# Gravando intervalo de datas, com dias uteis em Dictionary

Tags: c#, range

Estou precisando construir dois métodos em meu sistema, que faça o seguinte:

1) Gravar num `dictionary<T>` no C#, um *range* de datas. Para isto tenho uma função que consumo no *SQLServer* aqui da empresa, que me retorna um inteiro de dias úteis. O Padrão de arquitetura já está estabelecido desta forma, então tenho que fazer isso desta forma;

A Função do *SQLServer*, eu consumo da seguinte maneira:

```
using (IDbConnection dbConnection = Connection)
{
    string sQuery = "select dbo.working_days(@dtUtil) as QuantidadeDiasUteis";
    dbConnection.Open();

    return dbConnection.Query<DiasUteis>(sQuery, new { dtUtil = 
    Convert.ToDateTime(DtDiaUtil) }).FirstOrDefault();

}
```

Obs.: Meu parâmetro de entrada é uma data futura, e ela me retorna a quantidade de dias úteis em um inteiro.

2) Depois de armazenadas as datas no `Dictionary`, necessito ler, consultar as datas.

Então ficaria mais ou menos assim a estrutura:

```
31/07/2018 = 1;
01/08/2018 = 3;
06/08/2018 = 4; ==> (Ignorou os Sábados e Domingos);
```

Preciso retornar estas informações!

Comment: Tem que ser um `Dictionary`? já que vai armazenar só datas não pode ser um `List<DateTime>`?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz 4 opções de métodos para calculo de datas, duas com lista e duas com `Dictionary`

Segue Código

```
public static List<DateTime> DatasUteis1(int quantidade)
{
    List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime data = DateTime.Today;
    for (int i = 1; i <= quantidade; i++)
    {
        if (data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            datas.Add(data.AddDays(i));
    }

    return datas;
}

public static List<DateTime> DatasUteis2(int quantidade)
{
    List<DateTime> datas = new List<DateTime>();
    DateTime data = DateTime.Today;
    for (int i = 1; i <= quantidade; i++)
    {
        if (data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            datas.Add(data.AddDays(i));
        else
            quantidade++;
    }

    return datas;
}

public static Dictionary<int, DateTime> DatasUteis3(int quantidade)
{
    Dictionary<int, DateTime> datas = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
    DateTime data = DateTime.Today;
    for (int i = 1; i <= quantidade; i++)
    {
        if (data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            datas.Add(i, data.AddDays(i));
    }

    return datas;
}

public static Dictionary<int, DateTime> DatasUteis4(int quantidade)
{
    Dictionary<int, DateTime> datas = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();
    DateTime data = DateTime.Today;
    for (int i = 1; i <= quantidade; i++)
    {
        if (data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && data.AddDays(i).DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            datas.Add(i, data.AddDays(i));
        else
            quantidade++;
    }

    return datas;
}
```

Como você disse que o retorno do banco é quantidade de dias úteis, passei isso no parâmetro do método, o método `DatasUteis1` e `DatasUteis3` pulam os finais de semana e consideram apenas a quantidade exata de dias passado como parâmetro, já os métodos `DatasUteis2` e `DatasUteis4` consideram a quantidade total de dias úteis informado.

Também coloquei no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AcPJnD) para referencia.

Comment: Bom dia! As lógicas estão ótimas e muito bem fáceis de entender, porém o que eu preciso é para cada data que eu informo como parâmetro de entrada, na função do SQLServer, eu retorno a data e quantos dias úteis tem para a mesma. Exemplo:

Comment: Bom dia! Agradeço muito a ajuda, As lógicas estão ótimas e muito bem fáceis de entender, porém o que eu preciso é para cada data que eu informo como parâmetro de entrada, na função do SQLServer, eu retorno a data e quantos dias úteis tem para a mesma. Exemplo:

01/08/2018, 1
02/08/2018, 2
03/08/2018, 3
04/08/2018, 3
05/08/2018, 3
06/08/2018, 4

Onde: <Data do Dia>, <qtd dias uteis>

Comment: Na função do SQLServer eu passo como parâmetro de entrada um intervalo de datas <DataInicial>,<DataFinal>.

A questão do uso do dicionário foi proposital, pois estes retorno serão utilizados numa função de cálculo mais pra frente no projeto. Sendo assim não queremos que a cada chamada no método de cálculo, seja aberta uma conexão no banco. Para tanto, executaremos isso uma vez só na inicialização da aplicação, em um Singleton ou outro padrão para iniciar junto com a aplicação.

Comment: Dúvida: 1) Você informa uma data futura e sempre contará de hoje até essa data futura, certo? ou a data inicial pode ser amanhã, por exemplo?2) no caso o dia 04 e 05 são finais de semana, eles devem estar na lista?

Comment: Eu atualizei o [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AcPJnD) com o método 5, nele se é informado 7 dias úteis, ele irá mostrar os próximos 7 dias úteis